# Binding view using model data minor issue ? MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to bind the model class to my view i.e strongly typed . 
My model class :

```
 public class LeadSortModel
    {
        public string Contact_Name { get; set; }
        public string Contact_Address { get; set; }
```

In my view i am trying like this :

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Contact_Name) 
 @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Contact_Address)
```

**On my OUTPUT screen I am getting like** 
Contact_address : 
Contact_name :  ..... **But instead i want to get Contact Address with a space and no '_' in between .**

In model class properties with a space in b/w is not possible so i am looking for some better alternative does my need.

Any work around is quite helpful . Else shall i go Like ContactAddress and ...

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `[DisplayName("")]` from  `System.ComponentModel` namespace attribute for this

```
  public class LeadSortModel
            {
            [DisplayName("Contact Name")]   
            public string Contact_Name { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Contact Address")] 
            public string Contact_Address { get; set;
```

In the view

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Contact_Name)
```

will generate

```
<label for="Contact_Name">Contact Name</label>
```

Comment: under which namespace it is present ? i need to add any reference ?

Answer (score 1):

Use **DisplayName** attribute of **DataAnnotations** like this:

```
public class LeadSortModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Contact Name")]
        public string Contact_Name { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Contact Address")]
        public string Contact_Address { get; set; }
     }
```